# Remove empty space between items during transition

Tags: css, css-transitions, owl-carousel, translate3d, owl-carousel-2

I'm using Owl Carousel to create a slideshow.

When I use the same background color for all carousel items an empty space is displayed during the transition between items.

This issue only occurs using Chrome browser.

Please see an example with the issue happening: 
[jsfiddle.net/7yd04b1p/7](https://jsfiddle.net/7yd04b1p/7/)

[image]

I found that Owl Carousel is using CSS3 translate3d to do the slide transitions and I think Chrome is rendering this in a different way.

```js
doTranslate: function(pixels) {
  return {
    "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(" + pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
    "-moz-transform": "translate3d(" + pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
    "-o-transform": "translate3d(" + pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
    "-ms-transform": "translate3d(" + pixels + "px, 0px, 0px)",
    "transform": "translate3d(" + pixels + "px, 0px,0px)"
  };
},
```

Anyone have any idea how to solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your JS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: 3000,
    navigation: true,
    slideSpeed: 300,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    singleItem: true
  });
  // Add this code
  var widthItem = $(".owl-item").width();
  $(".owl-item .item").css("width", widthItem +1)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
.owl-wrapper {
  background: #000;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/breezy/Lrrebcjw/

Comment: This solve the problem, but in my case each item's background color are set dynamically from a CMS, so I don't know what background color will be set and each item can have different background, but thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: No problem. If this helped you mind marking this as the answer?